# Autoranging PlotWidget without padding (pyqtgraph)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I was searching for a half of day for this without luck. I have a PlotWidget that I want to autorange. Yet if it does, it has this "padding" (in other words the range is a bit larger then actual range). Do you know a way of avoiding this padding while keeping autoranging.

Comment: Please show some code and explain what you mean by autoranging.

Answer (score 1):

The `autoRange` method actually has a padding parameter. By default this is `None` which means the padding is between 0.02 and 0.1 depending on the size of the ViewBox. See the docs [here](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.autoRange).

By setting `padding=0` you get no padding.

Answer (score 0):

The pyqtgraph autoranging forces non-zero padding. You can see this in the source code for updateAutoRange() at http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ViewBox/ViewBox.html#ViewBox.autoRange

I had the same no padding objective and added my own auto-ranging code.  It adjusts the Y-axis maximum based on the maximum value of input data, while maintaining zero pad.

```
yMax = max(Y)
existingViewRect = self.ui.myGraph.plotItem.getViewBox().viewRange()
yMaxInView = existingViewRect[1][1]
if (yMax < 80):
    self.ui.myGraph.setYRange(0, 100, padding=0)
elif yMax > yMaxInView:
    self.ui.myGraph.setYRange(0, 2*yMaxInView, padding=0)
elif (yMax < yMaxInView/2):
    self.ui.myGraph.setYRange(0, yMaxInView/2, padding=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For my future self.

I used

```py
pg.ViewBox.suggestPadding = lambda *_: 0.0
```

to disable padding for good when something gets drawn.

However, `setRange` and the relatives from `PlotWidget` and `GraphicsView` still require `padding=0.0` parameter, for they do not respect the `ViewBox` padding.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is a derivative of what user 'Baron' suggested - implementing my own auto-ranging. I realized that `existingViewRect = self.ui.myGraph.plotItem.getViewBox().viewRange()` by default gets me the data with padding which is also used in the default auto-ranging. So it was as simple as determining the length of my data manually and setting the padding to 0.

```
max_x_value = len(self.data['Close']) # replace self.data['Close'] with your data
self.graphWidget.setXRange(0, max_x_value, padding=0)
```

This is an example for the x-axis, but the same can be done for the y-axis.